# Restart CSS3 animation from where it left off?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, css-animations

I wish to create an animation where upon every click of a button, an object moves a certain amount to its right.

e.g If the initial position of the object was say "left:10px" and every 1 loop of animation moves it by say 10px, then after first click it should be at 20px, after second click it should be at 30px and so on.

How should I go about doing that ? Right now CSS animations seem to restart from the initial position of the object upon every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-jQuery version with CSS doing the animation. Javascript is needed to set `left` and then `transition: left` controls the animation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/UEt4Y/

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'move-me' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {

    var move = document.getElementById( 'move' );
    move.style.left = ( move.offsetLeft + 10 ) + 'px';

}, false );
```

HTML:

```html
<button id="move-me">Move</button>
<div id="move"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#move {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transition:             left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:    left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:      left 250ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: left 250ms ease-in-out;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, at least you can not do something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes move{
  0% {}
100% {
     -webkit-transform: translate(10px);
     }  
}

   This will not work at all.
```

However you can use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) instead. You can create animations easily with it using [very few lines](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#book').animate({
        left: '+=10'
    }, 1000, function() {
        console.log("Done.");
    });
});
```

Live Demo: **[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AcPpp/)**

Hope this will help you out.

---

### ADDED

So you need to use CSS3 for the animation part. You can use `transition` in CSS like this:

```
-webkit-transition:left .3s ease-in-out;
```

and use JavaScript to change its `left` (JavaScript is *not* involved in the animation part).

Live Demo **(new)**: **[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PvNBB/)**

Comment: Actually I am shifting from a javascript animation to a CSS animation as this needs to be deployed on an android app and javascript animations are too jerky.

Comment: Created a [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PvNBB/), not using jQuery animation anymore, instead it's using CSS.